# Is it considered as global variable? struct and linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, global-variables

I searched, but couldn't find strict answer for my question. 
I have to write project using dynamic structures of data, but **I can't use global variables** . I want to use linked list of linked list. I found this code on the forum ([a linked list of linked lists in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768334/a-linked-list-of-linked-lists-in-c)) and it works great for me, but I'm not sure if this part is considered as global variable.

```
typedef struct sToy {
    char name[50];
    struct sToy *next;
}tToy;

typedef struct sChild {
    char name[50];
    tToy *firstToy;
    struct sChild *next;
} tChild;
```

I mean the "tToy" and "tChild" thing. Couse head has been declared in the main.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Those are type aliases; not global variables.

Comment: No variable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @WhozCraig said, those are struct type aliases, not global variables. Here's a sample code to show how you could use those structs as global variables or local variables:

```
typedef struct sToy {
    char name[50];
    struct sToy *next;
}tToy;

typedef struct sChild {
    char name[50];
    tToy *firstToy;
    struct sChild *next;
} tChild;

tToy Gtoy;//global
tChild Gchild;//global

int main() {
 tToy Ltoy;//local
 tChild Lchild;//local
}
```

You could also have omitted the "sToy" and "sChild", leaving just "typedef struct {...} alias;"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide only one local variable - pointer to the head to list of children and some functions to operate on the list.

Here you have two example functions - one append the child, another one append the toy to the toy list for the child. Of course you will need more of them but it is just something to start from:

```
tChild *appendChild(tChild **head, const char *name)
{
     tChild *result = NULL;
     tChild *current = *head;

     while (current != NULL && current ->next != NULL) current = current->next;
     if ((result = malloc(sizeof(tChild))) != NULL)
     {
         if (*head == NULL)
         {
             *head = result;
         }
         else
         {
             current->next = result;
             if (name != NULL) strncpy(result->name, name, sizeof((tChild) {0}.name));
             result->name[sizeof((tChild) { 0 }.name) - 1] = 0; //just in case
             result->firstToy = NULL;
             result->next = NULL;
         }
     }
     return result;
}

tToy *appendToy(tChild *child, const char *name)
{
    tToy *result = NULL;
    tToy *current;

    if (child != NULL)
    {
        current = child->firstToy;
        while (current != NULL && current->next != NULL) current = current->next;
        if ((result = malloc(sizeof(tToy))) != NULL)
        {
            if (child->firstToy == NULL)
            {
                child ->firstToy = result;
            }
            else
            {
                current->next = result;
                if (name != NULL) strncpy(result->name, name, sizeof((tToy) { 0 }.name));
                result->name[sizeof((tToy) { 0 }.name) - 1] = 0; //just in case
                result->next = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And something how to start in the main

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    tChild *head = NULL;

    if (appendChild(&head, "John") == NULL)
        printf("Error - appendingh the child failed\n");
    if (appendChild(&head, "Mark") == NULL)
        printf("Error - appendingh the child failed\n");
.....
```